# jax vmap: enforce correct shape

Tags: python, vectorization, jax

I'm using [vmap](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#jax.vmap) to vectorize parts of my code. Here is a minimal example, before the vectorization:

```
dim = 2
def sum(x):
    a = np.ones((dim,))
    return np.dot(x, a)

num_samples = 100
samples = np.ones((num_samples, dim))

sum(samples[0]) # 2
```

with vmap:

```
sum = vmap(sum)
sum(samples) # DeviceArray of shape (100,), all entries are 2
```

But this can go wrong, after vectorization:

```
sum(samples[0]) # DeviceArray of shape (2,2), all entries are 1
```

What happens here is that `samples[0]` has the shape `(2,)`. The vectorized function call splits its input argument along the first axis and is therefore fed 2 arrays of shape `(1,)`. Due to broadcasting with `a`, the resulting output has the shape `(2,)` again and is stacked to a `(2,2)` array.

This seems dangerous to me. The code looks normal and it would be easy for the resulting output to get consumed by some other broadcasting rules that hide its broken shape.

Is it possible to enforce the correct shape?

Answer (score 1):

**"This seems dangerous to me. The code looks normal and it would be easy for the resulting output to get consumed by some other broadcasting rules that hide its broken shape."**

Notice that `vmap` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do here, i.e. vectorizing the zeroth dimension, and the numpy broadcasting is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing. The issue, of course, is that the user is giving an array with the wrong shape, since `vmap` expects a vectorized input in the zeroth dimension of x. Instead the user should write

```
sum(samples[0:1])
```

which keeps the proper shape.

In other words: If you're going to apply vmap to a function, you can't use that function exactly as if you had never applied vmap in the first place. You need to account for the changed behavior of the function.

**"Is it possible to enforce the correct shape?"**

`vmap` by itself does not have the ability to enforce the shape of the input. If you were particularly concerned about the user giving the wrong shape to the function, you could build this into the original function. For example,

```
def sum(x): 
    if (x.shape[-1] != dim): 
        raise Exception() 
    a = np.ones((dim,)) 
    return np.dot(x, a)
```

will break if you don't give it the right shape, even after applying `vmap`.